# What formula can be used to identify the number of points required in drawing desired line count?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have to draw lines through a given points. Each point has to draw a line through other points. It draws only in one direction. So there is no duplicate lines passing through same points.

Now, I have been restricted to draw only 1000 lines. So I want to know how many points will I need to draw the stated count of lines? What is the formula that I can use to get the number of points required?

I thought of (n + 1) + (n + 2) + ( n + 3) + ..... = 1000. But don't know if this is right, as I have to put n = 0 to satisfy my equation.

Here is the illustration of what I am attempting:

[image: illustration of points and lines]

Please let me know what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the triangle numbers, in your diagram there are 10 lines, $\frac12n(n+1)$ with $n=4$, or use $\frac12n(n-1)$ with $n=5$.

Then to find out how many points are needed for 1000 lines, or the closest $n$ possible, form a quadratic equation and solve.

Comment: But I don't know what is n? then how will it be possible to decide whether it is even or odd to chose the formula?

Comment: n is found by solving the quadratic equation 0.5n(n-1)=1000 (both formulae will give the same answer, because in the first after solving you'd have to add one to get the number of points)

Comment: true. but you have proposed two equations. one I suppose work when `n` is even and the other one when `n` is odd. Am I have a misconception?

Comment: (comment above was edited)

Comment: solving quadratic gives me an imaginary number if the line count is set to 500. Can you please tell me whether I am wrong?

Comment: check all the minus signs, it should be real, all the best with it

Comment: yes my bad. thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have $n$ points. Pick any point on the circle, and observe that $n-1$ lines emerges from that point. Also, every line is shared by $2$ points, so the total number of lines is $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

If you have $1000$ lines, then the minimum number of points is the smallest $n>0$ such that $1000\leq\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. This can be solved to yield $$\left\lceil \frac{1+3\sqrt{889}}{2}\right\rceil=46$$
[image]

Comment: Wow. that is one amazing solution. Thank you.